# How to save several files downloaded in a row in one folder with different extensions?

Tags: python

What is the best way to save files to a folder with their native extension? The idea is that files are being downloaded from several urls in turn and stored in three folders into three folders, depending on the status code. And all these files with different extensions .

```
import requests

def save_file(link):
    filename = link.split('/')[-1]
    print(filename)
    # proxies ={
        # 'https': 'http://5.135.240.70:8080'        
    # }
    data = requests.get('https://ipinfo.io/json')
    print(data.text)
    r =requests.get(link,allow_redirects=True)
    print(r.status_code)

    while True:
        if():
            if(r.status_code == 200):
                with open('\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\good\\gp.txt', 'wb') as f:               
                    f.write(r.content)                                                     
        if(r.status_code != 200):
            open(r'\Users\user\Desktop\bad\gp.zip', 'wb' ).write(r.content)
        break

    open(r'\Users\user\Desktop\general\gp.zip', 'wb').write(r.content)


link1 ='://...........................txt'
link2 ='://..............................jpeg'
link3 ='://..............................php'
link4 ='://........................rules'
```

In this form , it is more suitable for downloading one specific file . Maybe through the "glob" or "os.". I am grateful for any suggestions and help.

I am interested in this particular part of the code:

```
     while True:
        if():
            if(r.status_code == 200):
                with open('\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\good\\gp.txt', 'wb') as f:               
                    f.write(r.content)                                                     
        if(r.status_code != 200):
            open(r'\Users\user\Desktop\bad\gp.zip', 'wb' ).write(r.content)
        break

    open(r'\Users\user\Desktop\general\gp.zip', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Comment: Are the links in the form `://*.txt` or is there nothing separating the file name from the extension (no period)?

Comment: they are all standard url format. here is an example of a link.   there is nothing https://www.binarydrtyefense.com/banlist.txt

Answer (score 0):

As you suspected, the `os` module can come in handy in this case.
You can use the following syntax to get the file name and extension

```py
file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(link))
```

What is happening is that you are first getting the full file name using basename e.g. if your url is `https://www.binarydrtyefense.com/banlist.txt` basename would return `banlist.txt`. Then splitext takes the `banlist.txt` and produces a tuple `('banlist', '.txt')`.

Later in your code you can use this to make the file e.g.

```py
download_name = f'gp{file_ext}'
download_dir = 'good' if r.status_code == 200 else 'bad'
download_path = os.path.join(r'\Users\user\Desktop', download_dir, download_name)
```

Comment: thank you! I've been looking for two days to solve this problem!

Comment: I apologize for the possibly stupid question. I changed my code to your version, the url is being searched, but nothing is being written to the folders (the path is correct). Thanks !